# PL/SQL:set output value with reflection

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, reflection, plsql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
Procedure MyProc
(
Output1 OUT VARCHAR2
Output2 OUT VARCHAR2
Output3 OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT mt.value
from myTable mt
join all_arguments aa on aa.argument_name=mt.key;
END myProc;
```

How can I put mt.Value into the corresponding argument (i.e. `Output1`, `output2`, or `output3`?)

EDIT: More details needed

So, I have my output parameters `Output1`, `Output2`, and `Output3`,
and my table contains the following>

```
CREATE TABLE myTable ( key, value ) AS
SELECT 'Output1', 'Result1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Output2', 'Result2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Output3', 'Result3' FROM DUAL;
```

So, at the end, I want to return `Result1` in `Output1`, `Result2` in `Output2`, and `Result3` in `Output3`

The purpose is to have a very flexible procedure, as the number of returned values is huge, can be changed, and I want to add at least lines as possible.

Right now, when, I add an output, I need to add an output in my list of output parameters (This one cannot be avoid), but I need to add a condition in my list as well, to say

```
IF mt.key='Output4' THEN mt.Value Into Output4
```

I want to avoid this last declaration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statement for `myTable` and DML statements for some example data that illustrates your problem and also state what your expected output is.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Would it be appropriate to define a collection (`CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);`) and then `BULK COLLECT INTO` that collection and return one collection with a variable number of items rather than variable numbers of out parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One can use `into`:

```
select mt.value into output1
from myTable mt join
     all_arguments aa
     on aa.argument_name = mt.key;
```

Comment: There are likely to be multiple rows from the joined tables (since there are expected to be 3 outputs and each will be in a separate row) and `SELECT ... INTO ...` can only handle a single row.

Comment: @MT0 . . . "How can I put mt.Value into the corresponding argument".  That is what `INTO` does.

Comment: When the query returns multiple rows then you will get `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. That is what `INTO` does when you are expecting the query to match on 3 rows (i.e. one per output).

Comment: @MT0 . . . If the query returns more than one row or no rows, then the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The OP appears to be trying to do something "clever" with reflection - it sort-of makes sense (they have a variable number of rows and want to assign them to out parameters) but it is also probably not the solution that they should be aiming for as they appear to have an XY-Problem and are asking about how to complete their over-complicated solution and not about better solutions to the same problem.